# Extract file content from signature (openssl)

Tags: openssl, signature

I have a csvs signed file and the certificate for this signature.
With this i can extract the public key and the signature and use them to verify the signature of the file using openssl.

What i want to know is if there are some way to extract the content of the original file from the signature to validate the signature manually.

Anyone can help me with this?

i have something like:

```
asda
asd
asdaddasdas
adsasdasdasd
dasdasdasdasdasd,231231231231123123123
ZVkoqGNQ+JIFdLCLMZdiPlRwE/go2X3BHJLEVxj1tdYdoBnYL/uoRVFY/YC/FGQqBz25AzoXkjS6Eei9+i+uTlT0D74IC0aeU18QnCMqrOORyJD32yGI0M7Asmm7dRwgP10hmw3mOEmnjMeNHs+OBOD70UVhhByBirTG04xmh6DWk08rbRzJLTx+b7wOAC2J8wGBt5TwD7OwyRDHdLOgEx5TWwJsgMCUwTOdbodgIIiCLnFJJcoDuQpvg==
```

with this and the certificate i can verify the file.

I wnat to use only `ZVkoqGNQ+JIFdLCLMZdiPlRwE/go2X3BHJLEVxj1tdYdoBnYL/uoRVFY/YC/FGQqBz25AzoXkjS6Eei9+i+uTlT0D74IC0aeU18QnCMqrOORyJD32yGI0M7Asmm7dRwgP10hmw3mOEmnjMeNHs+OBOD70UVhhByBirTG04xmh6DWk08rbRzJLTx+b7wOAC2J8wGBt5TwD7OwyRDHdLOgEx5TWwJsgMCUwTOdbodgIIiCLnFJJcoDuQpvg==`

and the certificate or the publickey to get:

```
asda
asd
asdaddasdas
adsasdasdasd
```

or

```
asda
asd
asdaddasdas
adsasdasdasd
dasdasdasdasdasd,231231231231123123123
```

there are any way to do it with openssl or other tool?

Or if it's not possible there any way to get the ash from the signature and create the signed ash from the content and match the ash's?

Comment: The signature is a one way process. You can't reverse the process.  So there is no way to do what you ask.  I.e. To verify a signature you will always need the data, the signature to verify and the public key.

Comment: There any way to get the ash from the signature and create the signed ash from the content and match the ash's?

Comment: By 'ash', I assume you mean 'hash'.  A digital signature IS a hash.  So you are creating a hash of a hash?  Not really a good idea.  I think you need to rethink what you are trying to achieve as it seems like you are trying to make a solution fit your problem when it doesn't.

Comment: Actually i already am capable to check if the signature is valid from the beginning using openssl.
But a guy want to check visually if the signature match the content in some way...

Comment: And then your back to the start.  Is "verify" the data, you need the "data", "signature" and the "public key".  With these three you can "verify" that the data is the data that was signed and that it was signed with the private key of the supplied public key.  There is no way around this.